# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption - with Webspshere 9.0.0.3

Tags: sql-server, websphere

we deployed an application in WebSphere application server 9.0.0.3 and connecting to a SQL server 2014 database. But While connecting to the database we are getting below SQL exception error. Could you please assist on this issue.
Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1352)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1466)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1042)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:568)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:625)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question about the same exception on DeveloperWorks has an accepted answer:

[Why am I getting a "java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response" error when trying to configure the WAS datasource to use TLS 1.2 when connecting to Microsoft SQL Database?](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/387148/why-am-i-getting-a-javaioioexception-sql-server-di/)

Try following the same steps and see if this resolves it for you.